# What is the best and worst case for the following snippet?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

```
for (int index = 1; index < n; index *= 2) {
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < n) {
       counter++;
    }
}
```

Determine its best and worst case runtime in the Big-Theta notation as a function of n.

I think the worst case is n*log(n), but I am not sure about the best case.

Comment: Since the input is just `n` and nothing else varies, there is no notion of best/worst. It just has a fixed number of steps to perform for a given `n`. Just think of it. If `n` is 5 and you are sure of the worst case, then what would make it "better"? There is nothing you can use to change the behaviour once you know `n` is 5.

Comment: Here is a follow-up question for you, what will be the complexity if you replace `while (counter < n)` with `while (counter < index)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time complexity is indeed O(log), but there is no notion of best or worst.

Such notions of best or worst only play a role when there is some variation possible for a given . For instance, sorting algorithms get their time complexity expressed in the size of the input, but then there is still some variation in the way the input is ordered (is it already sorted? Is it sorted in reverse? ...etc).

In this problem, there is *only*  as input, nothing else, and so the time complexity is what it is -- no best, no worst.